# Tensorflow 2: Getting "WARNING:tensorflow:9 out of the last 9 calls to <function> triggered tf.function retracing. Tracing is expensive"

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I think this error is coming from a problem with shapes, but I have no idea where. The complete error message suggests to do the following:

> Also, tf.function has experimental_relax_shapes=True option that relaxes argument shapes that can avoid unnecessary retracing.

When I enter this argument in the function decorator, it does work.

```
@tf.function(experimental_relax_shapes=True)
```

What can the cause be? Here's the full code:

```
import os
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '3'
import tensorflow as tf
print(f'Tensorflow version {tf.__version__}')
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Conv1D, GlobalAveragePooling1D, Embedding
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model

(train_data, test_data), info = tfds.load('imdb_reviews/subwords8k',
                                          split=[tfds.Split.TRAIN, tfds.Split.TEST],
                                          as_supervised=True, with_info=True)

padded_shapes = ([None], ())

train_dataset = train_data.shuffle(25000).\
    padded_batch(padded_shapes=padded_shapes, batch_size=16)
test_dataset = test_data.shuffle(25000).\
    padded_batch(padded_shapes=padded_shapes, batch_size=16)

n_words = info.features['text'].encoder.vocab_size


class ConvModel(Model):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ConvModel, self).__init__()
        self.embe = Embedding(n_words, output_dim=16)
        self.conv = Conv1D(32, kernel_size=6, activation='elu')
        self.glob = GlobalAveragePooling1D()
        self.dens = Dense(2)

    def call(self, x, training=None, mask=None):
        x = self.embe(x)
        x = self.conv(x)
        x = self.glob(x)
        x = self.dens(x)
        return x


conv = ConvModel()

conv(next(iter(train_dataset))[0])

loss_object = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True)

train_loss = tf.keras.metrics.Mean()
test_loss = tf.keras.metrics.Mean()

train_acc = tf.keras.metrics.CategoricalAccuracy()
test_acc = tf.keras.metrics.CategoricalAccuracy()

optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=1e-3)


@tf.function
def train_step(inputs, labels):
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        logits = conv(inputs, training=True)
        loss = loss_object(labels, logits)
        train_loss(loss)
        train_acc(logits, labels)

    gradients = tape.gradient(loss, conv.trainable_variables)
    optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, conv.trainable_variables))


@tf.function
def test_step(inputs, labels):
    logits = conv(inputs, training=False)
    loss = loss_object(labels, logits)
    test_loss(loss)
    test_acc(logits, labels)


def learn():
    train_loss.reset_states()
    test_loss.reset_states()
    train_acc.reset_states()
    test_acc.reset_states()

    for text, target in train_dataset:
        train_step(inputs=text, labels=target)

    for text, target in test_dataset:
        test_step(inputs=text, labels=target)


def main(epochs=2):
    for epoch in tf.range(1, epochs + 1):
        learn()
        template = 'TRAIN LOSS {:>5.3f} TRAIN ACC {:.2f} TEST LOSS {:>5.3f} TEST ACC {:.2f}'

        print(template.format(
            train_loss.result(),
            train_acc.result(),
            test_loss.result(),
            test_acc.result()
        ))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(epochs=1)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TF/DR: Root-cause of this error is due to change in shape of `train_data` which varies from batch to batch. Fixing the size/shape of `train_data` resolves this tracing warning. I changed the following line, then everything works as expected. Full gist is [here](https://github.com/jvishnuvardhan/Stackoverflow_Questions/blob/master/tf_function_retracing_error.ipynb)

```
padded_shapes = ([9000], ())#None.
```

#### Details:

As mentioned in the warning message

> WARNING:tensorflow:10 out of the last 11 calls to <function train_step
> at 0x7f4825f6d400> triggered tf.function retracing. Tracing is
> expensive and the excessive number of tracings could be due to (1)
> creating @tf.function repeatedly in a loop, (2) passing tensors with
> different shapes, (3) passing Python objects instead of tensors. For
> (1), please  define your @tf.function outside of the loop. For (2),
> @tf.function has experimental_relax_shapes=True option that relaxes
> argument shapes that can avoid unnecessary retracing.

this retracing warning happens because of the three reasons mentioned in the warning message. Reason (1) is not the root-cause because @tf.function is not called in a loop, also reason (3) is not the root-cause because both the arguments of `train_step` and `test_step` are tensor objects. So the root-cause is the reason (2) mentioned in the warning.

When I printed the size of `train_data`, it printed different sizes. So I tried to pad `train_data` so that shape is same for all the batches.

```
 padded_shapes = ([9000], ())#None.  # this line throws tracing error as the shape of text is varying for each step in an epoch.
    # as the data size is varying, tf.function will start retracing it
    # For the demonstration, I used 9000 as max length, but please change it accordingly
```

Comment: 1. If data size of train dataset should be changed as the model trains(eg. progressive growing of gans(pggan)), so that I can't shape the size in advance, is this inevitable? 2. And is this warning means that I'm not taking any advantage of using @tf.function at all?

Answer (score 0):

I was following  @john-rocky  on [tensorflow-object-detection-api](https://rockyshikoku.medium.com/how-to-use-tensorflow-object-detection-api-with-the-colab-sample-notebooks-477707fadf1b)
This tutorial solves the problem of training images with ONE bbox in images [640,640,3] with RF Zoo.
I have tried to mount it with N bbox by image, and it gets the error.

```py
WARNING:tensorflow:5 of the last 5 calls to ....
```

In my case, After long investigation this error is due to *"tf.functions can only handle one predefined input form, if the form changes, or if different python objects are passed, tensorflow automatically rebuilds the function."*  @bela127  [comment 619036189](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/34025#issuecomment-619036189)

I explain in detail:

When entering `def train_step_fn` function values with format `[640,640,3]` for images and `[1,4]` for boxes. `@tf.function` causes a **graph to be created**. That graph gives you a ***lot of speed*** when entering.  In my case 10s for 460 images.

But I have `[N,4]` per image (there are some images with seven elements to bbox in a image [7,4] others [3,4]), that is to say each call to  `def train_step_fn` , ***TF has to create another graph***, because **they do not match the previous format**. This results in the error `tensorflow:5 of the last 5 calls` , and take 1320s for 460 images.

On the left the graphic card without the error `tensorflow:5 of the last 5 calls` on the right having to create new graphs constantly. (GPU with the error)
[image]

***Solution in my case***, the input format of the tensors to `def train_step_fn`, must be exactly the same. i.e. all images must have the same number of labelled boxes.